# Creating a KnockoutJS ViewModel with a post command to fill the ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to bind a model coming from the server over json to a viewmodel I create on the client and then bind it using Knockout.js to display the data.  I have the following code

```
function tireRunDataViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.load = function() {
            $.jQuery.post('./GetTireRunModel', { outingID: '@Model' }, function (result) {
                self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
            } , "json");
        };

        self.load();
    }

var viewModel = new tireRunDataViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

It appears as though self.data is not being set before the ko.applyBindings is being done.  Why is this and what can I do to make sure the self.data is being filled out before the applyBindings is being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `$.jQuery.post` is asynchronous, so the callback does not execute until it completes, which is after `ko.applyBindings` is called.

A couple of options:

- you could call `ko.applyBindings` in your callback.  If your application is not more complicated than this, then it can be an option to apply bindings after the AJAX call has completed.
- you could create `self.data` as an observable and then updated it in the callback like: `self.data(ko.mapping.fromJS(result));`.  Then in your UI you could use a `with` binding on `data` around the UI that depends on `data`, so that it is not rendered until it is ready.

Quick simulation of it: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Wf8E8/

Comment: I originally had the applybindings in the callback but I am trying to add some save functionality and refactoring is where I ran into this issue.

Comment: Then, the second option would probably be preferable.  Make `data` an observable and update it's value in the callback.